# A question regarding Lehmer-Pierce numbers for certain families of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+...+a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic, irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients and let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in\mathbb{C}$ be the complex roots of $f$, where we assume that none of the $\alpha_j$ is a root of unity. The kth Lehmer-Pierce number associated to $f$ is defined by $$\Delta_k(f):=\prod_{j=1}^n (\alpha_j^k-1). $$ Then $\Delta_k(f)$ is a (rational) integer, which had been studied by Pierce and subsequently by
Lehmer, where the latter tried to construct large primes using the sequence $\\{ \Delta_k(f) \\}$. There is a lot known regarding the behaviour of $\Delta_k(f)$ for different $k$, e.g. $$ \frac{\log\Delta_k(f)}{k}\to m(f) $$ as $k\to\infty$, where $m(f)=\int_0^1\log |f(e^{2\pi i \theta})| d\theta$ is the logarithmic Mahler measure of $f$. Now, my question is about what happens, when $k$ is assumed to be fixed and the polynomial $f$ is allowed to change. I am interested in the case of a sequence $\\{f_j\\}$ of polynomials such that their respective degrees go to $\infty$, while their (logarithmic) Mahler measures stay bounded, say $m(f_j)\leq C$ holds for all $j$, where $C$ is some positive constant. Is there anything known regarding sequences of the form $\\{\Delta_2(f_j)\\}$, for example any kind of asymptotics, lower and/or upper bounds? (I did choose $k=2$ for convenience) I have only numerically studied this sequence in case of certain Salem polynomials coming from the family of polynomials $$p_j(x)= x^j (x^3-x-1)+(x^3+x^2-1), $$
where a lower bound linear in the degree of the polynomial seemed to be realistic. For my purposes it would be actually sufficient to know that $|\Delta_2(f_j)|\neq 1$ for large enough $j$.

I would be grateful for any references to material, which you may consider relevant. It would also certainly help me to know, if sequences of the type $\\{ \Delta_k(f_j) \\}$ have not been studied at all.

Comment: You might want to insist on $f$ being irreducible, or at any rate not having any cyclotomic factors, lest $\Delta_k(f)=0$.

Comment: $\Delta_2(f)=f(1)f(-1)$ (up to sign, anyway), so if $f(x)=(x^2-1)g(x)+c$ then $\Delta_2(f)=c^2$.

Comment: You are completely right Gerry, I somehow forgot to include that condition

Comment: From the point of view of Mahler measure, interesting families are given by $f_j(x) = g(x,x^j)$ where $g$ is a 2-variable polynomial. In this situation we have $m(f_j) \to m(g)$ by a theorem of Boyd and Lawton.

Comment: There are results on error bounds for $m(f_j)-m(g)$ e.g. arXiv:2203.12259, but I am not aware of results about $\Delta_k(f_j)$ for fixed $k$.

Comment: Dear Francois, I was actually studying these kind of sequences and it looked like there was a lower bound for $\Delta_2(f)$ linear in the degree of $f$